# bootstrap carousel control responsive

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem on responsive view. How to make the left and right arrow as responsive. Below attach screenshot for responsive devices

*Website view*
[image: Wesbite view its ok]

*Mobile View*

[image: Moible view not ok]

```css
.carousel-control span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 85%;
  color: #C21B17;
  z-index:999px;
  font-size:30px;
}

.carousel-control.left {
 margin-left: -40px;
 width:30px;
 height:60px;
 background:none;
}
.carousel-control.right {
 margin-right: -20px; 
 width:30px;
 height:60px; 
 background:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just set the carousel controls to auto on width and height or use percentages to make sure it fills a certain amount of the page. For example let's say you want the controls to take up 20% of the page each and height doesn't matter too much. Then do the following.

```
.carousel-control.left {
    margin-left: -40px;
    width:20%;
    height: auto;
    background:none;
}
.carousel-control.right {
    margin-right: -20px; 
    width:20%;
    height: auto;   
    background:none;
}
```

Comment: it is still the same.